# MySQL Multiple table locks

Tags: mysql

I have a small curiosity about MySQL table locks.

Say I want to lock two tables. I execute this command:

```
LOCK TABLES table1 WRITE, table2 WRITE
```

And then I checked if the tables have indeed been locked by executing:

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES IN mydatabase WHERE In_use > 0
```

I have noticed tho that if I run two lock commands sequentitally for example:

```
LOCK TABLES table1 WRITE
LOCK TABLES table2 WRITE
```

And then check which tables are locked using the same command only table2 is marked as locked. Why is this so?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[LOCK TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html) is not transaction-safe and implicitly commits any active transaction before attempting to lock the tables.

So, in the first case, you have one transaction which hold 2 tables locked, in the second only one, because `LOCK TABLES table1 WRITE` had been commited

Answer (score 1):

Lock tables will first unlock all tables locked by the current session before performing the specified lock.   So the call to lock table 2 is unlocking table 1.